# Install PHP on Apache 2.2 Server on Linux System

Tags: php, linux, apache2, dedicated-server

I wanted to install php on my dedicated Apache Server version 2.2 on Linux System.

So please suggest me some link where I found accurate documentation or steps for installation with all configuration and setting.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the Linux-Distribution you use, you can use apt-get as package manager.
Then all you have to do is to install you php-package with it.

Example for Debian

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

(if you are logged in as root, you don't need sudo)

You also found such information on php.net:
    http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to httpd.conf

```
ScriptAlias /php/" c:/path-to-php-dir/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php.exe"
```

Then restart Apache and it should interpret php files correctly.

For more information on installing Apache with php look at the following manual page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.apache.php